# jQuery UI sortable handles not moving item before 50%

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

my question is about jQuery UI's sortable function. It works very well, with the exception of one thing that I want to tweak. It's not an error within jQUI or anything, it's just something I want to see if I can change.

I have [this here fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrrGu/) to show you what I mean. The element is draggable by the handle, but the element only shifts after the handle has been dragged over halfway across the element to its right. Is there any way to tweak this?

```
$('ul').sortable({
    handle: '.move'
});
```

Thanks!
Chad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tolerance: 'pointer'` like this:

```
$('ul').sortable({
    handle: '.move',
    tolerance: 'pointer'
});
```

**[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/qrrGu/2/)**